# PHP - preg_match - How to match number beginning with zero

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match to match numbers that start with a zero to indicate an invalid input. Numbers such as `01`, `0023`, `00.4` are invalid; however numbers such as `0.12` are valid. The input would be a calculator entry, such as `09 * 108 + 0.19 + 4009`. In this case, the expression would be invalid because of the `09`.

So far my expression looks like: `preg_match("/[^1-9]+0[0-9]+/", $subject)`

What I tried to do was match when a zero precedes any string of digits, but is also not preceded by another string of digits. So `109` is valid, but 1+09 is invalid. However it isn't working for cases like `1 + 4009`.

Comment: Start with zero = `^0`. RegEx `^0\d+$`. Not starts with zero `^[^0]`

Comment: Maybe `0\.\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b0\d+`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @chris85, your answer works well. I've never seen the SKIP, FAIL expressions used before. Can you explain a bit about what they mean?

Comment: You can read more about them here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex and http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#pcrevariation. Looks like the answer below will work for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\b0[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b/', $subject)
```

`\b` for word boundary.